# change default value in input tag

Tags: forms, reactjs, textfield, placeholder, default-value

I am using react-form to create an input form. I am using the  tag. I want to pre-populate the input field, but I want the user to still be able to change the default value that is entered. React is the front end language that I am using. I tried setting the readOnly field inside the input tag to false. It allows me to click on the field but I still cant backspace the default day and change it to something else.

When I use a placeholder, instead of having the input tag at all, there is an overlap problem (check the image attached). once you enter in a value, there is no problem as the "Due Date" moves up higher with the existing functionality.

I would need the placeholder to only show up when I click on the "Due Date" field to enter a value, or be able to alter the default value when using the input tag. I am using react version 16.2.0[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNGZu.png)

```html
              <Field
                name="dueDayOfFilingPeriod"
                component={TextField}
                floatingLabelText="Due Date"
                floatingLabelStyle={(props.hasFilingFormName || props.hasPreference) ? {} : styles.floatingLabelStyle}
                floatingLabelFocusStyle={styles.floatingLabelFocusStyle}
                disabled={props.hasFilingFormName}
                style={styles.inline}
              >
                <input value= {props.filingInfo.dueDate}/>
              </Field>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a `defaultValue` prop instead of a `value` prop on the `<input />`. This pattern is usually called an uncontrolled component since you only set the starting value, you can read more here: https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html

To make it a controlled component, where the value is always being set relative to the state of your component, you need to add an `onChange` handler to the `<input />` component and update the state with the new value. You can read more on controlled components here: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: Neither of these solutions work in my case, and here is why I believe this is the case. When I set the default value to {props.filingInfo.dueDate} it leaves the field blank. I believe this is because at the time the form gets created, the filingInfo object is empty. When I enter the form name in a previous input box, an api call is made which returns the filingInfo object and places it in store. Also, this component is a stateless component, so the onChange can't use the this.setstate.

Comment: You can remount the stateless component once the API call is complete by applying a `key` property to the component like so: `<StatelessComponent key="loaded" />`. Upon remounting it would correctly apply the `defaultValue` on the input.

Otherwise you can define the `onChange` handler in the parent component and pass it to the stateless component as a prop. So then the input would look something like `<input value={this.props.value} onChange={this.props.onChange} /> `

If neither solution works please share more of your codebase

Comment: This helped lead to the solution to my problem. the only thing I did differently was add a conditional statement. If I set it to value, I could not set value to the due date returned by the api call inside the function component (i mistakenly said it was a stateless component). So my line of code for the input was this: <input value={props.value == -1? props.filingInfo.dueDate : props.value } onChange={props.handleChange}/>